# SQL Query / find percentile based on rank

Tags: mysql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I have created the following tables with ranks for a data set:

```
Position  Index IndexL IndexH Amount Rank
1          2.5    2      3     2000   1     
1          2.5    2      3     3000   2
1          2.5    2      3     4000   3
1          2.5    2      3     5000   4
1          2.5    2      3     6000   5

2          1.5    1      2     2500   1     
2          1.5    1      2     4500   2
2          1.5    1      2     6700   3
2          1.5    1      2     8900   4
2          1.5    1      2     9900   5
```

Now I want to find the percentile based on the ranks created using the indices such that I get the following output :

```
Position Amount 
1         3000+(4000-3000)*(2.5-2)
2         2500+(4500-2500)*(1.5-1)
```

Can someone help me with this. I am kinda new to SQL world.

Thanks,
Monica

Comment: I have seen today similar question

Comment: Did you expect one row for each distinct value of `Position` in result?

Comment: yes. Each position will have 1 row

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do what you want with the `percentile_cont()` aggregation function.  It looks like you want the median:

```
SELECT position,
       PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Amount) as Median
from t
group by position;
```

You can read more about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions110.htm).

Comment: Hi do i still need to use Percectile_cont now that I have already calculated ranks. I think using the ranks 2 and 3 and interpolating the value in between them should give me the result right ?

Comment: @Monica . . . You are probably better off using `percentile_cont()` -- if you can get away with it.  You have to do an aggregation anyway, to get only one row per `position`.  (If you want the median on each row, you can also use `percentile_cont()` as an analytic function.)

Answer (score 0):

You can have Oracle assign a percentile for you using the [`NTILE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions115.htm) analytic function:

```
SELECT
  position,
  amount,
  NTILE(100) OVER (PARTITION BY POSITION ORDER BY amount)
FROM myTable
```

I'm not sure if the result will match your calculations (I'm a bit hazy on some of my statistics). If not, please try the `PERCENTILE_CONT` solution proposed by @GordonLinoff, or else you can try the [`PERCENT_RANK`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions126.htm#i1043951) analytic function - just replace `NTILE(100)` in the query above with `PERCENT_RANK()`.

Comment: Hi I have already calculated ranks using row_number and paritition which is in the first table. Now in order to get the final output I only need to use the data in this table and do the calculation as shown - like for Position 1, take the Amount with ranks 2 and 3 (IndexL and IndexH) and inetpolate the value using the ratio.

Comment: You can get following values with the `LEAD` function: `LEAD(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY Position ORDER BY Rank)`. That will return null for the last row in the partition though, so if you want to default it to something do `LEAD(Amount, 1, your-default-value)`. I'm afraid I don't understand your expected output - is that *everything* you want to see or just two sample rows?